# Microsoft Access can't create this relationship

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to create a relationship in Access but I get this error.

[image]

The problem is that in the table `[Attributes]` there isn't any record!

What could be the reason for this error?

[image]
[image]

This is the `Field Property` of `[Attributes].[Personal Data Categories]`:

[image]

Comment: The error is saying that there *is* data in the 'Personal Data Cat...' table that should match data in the Attributes table, but the data in Attributes does not exist. Is there some data in the 'Personal Data Cat...' table?

Comment: Your problem is caused by using a lookup field. Only use a lookup field for (normally) fixed values like gender or (less fixed but rather fixed though) VAT rates. In all other cases, stay away from them: [ The Evils of Lookup Fields in Tables](http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm)

Comment: The field [Attributes].[Personal Data Categories] suggests to me that each Attribute can refer to a record in [Personal Data Categories] table? In which case you're attempting to create the relationship in the wrong direction.